# Python - Same variable in if statement

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

Is there a shorter form for something like:

```
if v or v == 0:
```

v can be None or an int. If it is not None or 0, go in.

Comment: You can use `if v` ? (but your code example contradicts your explanation somewhat...)

Comment: Your condition is *false* when `v = None`.

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to get shorter than that.  You have 2 very different conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
if v is not None:
    # code
```

To test it:

```
l = [None, 0, 13, -123]

for i in l:
    if i is not None:
        print i
```

Ouput:

```
0
13
-123
```

Comment: Difficult to tell what the OP is really after, but this doesn't quite match *If it is not None or 0, go in.*

Answer (score -1):

None and 0 all represent false, other int except zero are represent true. If you just don't want false,you can use：

```
if not v:
     pass
```

Comment: `if not v` is when it is *false* - the opposite of *If you just don't want false*